# Select Date from Excel sheet that may be in one of many formats

Tags: sql, vba, date, ms-access

In Access, I am transferring several columns (not all) from a spreadsheet to an Access table. It works fine so long as the date on the excel sheet is in the same format as the Access table, that format being "mm/dd/yyyy".

However, not all of the dates on the excel sheets are in the format "mm/dd/yyyy". Sometimes it is Mon-dd-yyyy, and sometimes dd/mm/yyyy. I am currently using a simple select statement to put the date in the access table, so the date transfers when it is in the correct format (mm/dd/yyyy) and leaves the date column blank for that entry when it is in any other format.

Is there a way I can ensure the date is always formatted as "mm/dd/yyyy" before selecting it into the access table?

Comment: Does excel recognise all the cells as dates?

Comment: Sorry if you say my earlier comment, I misread that. It does mark them as dates in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to format all dates in mm/dd/yyyy format before loading them to Access table.

Comment: Well, there is a world outside the US, so the single proper way is to format as yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Do you mean format them in the excel sheet? or how would I do this in vba? I'm first transferring the spreadsheet to a temporary table, then using SQL to extract only the columns I need, but the dates don't show up even in this temporary table

Comment: Can you share the code you use? you could always use Day/Month/Year functions on the data before extracting to put the data in a single format